# Is the case described below hypothetical or does it occur in natural languages?

Tags: syntax, morphology, linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, cases

Suppose that you have a language, let's say it's SVO, has a clause pattern in which the subject typically stands for an agent or experiencer and the object typically stands for a patient or stimulus, and in which neither NP is overtly marked for case.

Now suppose that the language has a different clause pattern in which the first argument in the clause takes an overtly marked case, let's call it "case-B," and the subject typically stands for a patient or stimulus while the object, which has no overt case-marking, typically stands for an agent or experiencer.

This second clause pattern is like the passive, except that there's no valency reduction, and the second argument must be an indefinite pronoun if its referent is to be unspecified.

My question is, is there a natural language with such a scheme?

Comment: I find it hard to test the languages I know against the requirements without further details. For instance, what happens to the verb in your second construction? Does it have to remain in exactly the same form? And what do you mean by no overt case-marking? Do you tolerate prepositions or do you admit only non-declensional bare NP/DP? Finally, how universal should this construction be possible (the reason I ask is that I want to test your requirements against anaphors in subject position)?

Comment: In the second case, why would you call the first argument the subject and the second the object rather than vice versa? Semantically, it would make more sense the other way around. Is there some other criterion by which subject and object can be identified, e.g. verb agreement?

Comment: @ TKR:   I'm not sure that the criteria for subject-hood are semantic.  Recall English passives, like "The cat was run over," in which the subject stands for a patient.  As for the syntactic properties of the subject, it would be deleted by EQUI and referenced by switch-reference marking.

Comment: @Olivier:  Silly me, I didn't even think of these issues.  But now that you mention it, the verb's form would be the same in both constructions, and no overt case-marking would mean that nouns not in case-B would have a zero-form case marking.   Come to think of it, the subjects of these constructions could not be omitted for EQUI.   As far as I can tell, there is no reason why this language couldn't have adpositions.  Finally, I don't know what a "non-declensional NP/DP" is, and don't understand your last question.  Consequently, I look forward to your next comment.

Comment: [Acehnese "Passive"](www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aceh.html) has some of these characteristics, except there's no overt case markers in the language.

Comment: So, just to clarify, your first clause pattern would be like the English "dog bites man", while the equivalent clause written in your second pattern would be something like "man-of bites dog", where "-of" is a hypothetical patient/stimulus case marker? If so, no, I'm not personally aware of any language that would (commonly) use both of these clause patterns, but I wouldn't find it implausible e.g. in a language transitioning between a fixed SVO clause pattern with no case markers (like English) and a more free-form clause pattern with overtly marked case (like e.g. many other IE languages).

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your model correctly, it describes an ergative structure within many natural languages, dead or living.

E.g. Sumerian, Georgian, Basque and Tibetan all have the ergative patterns, where an agent of a transitive verb is marked, while the patiens of a transitive verb with a logical subject is not.

The subjects of nontransitive verbs in these languages, on the other hand, have no special markers.

Comment: Well, what I described is not an ergative/absolutive system.  If it were, you'd have the subject marked with ergative case in the first pattern.

Comment: Not necessarily, there are many languages with split-ergativity. AFAIK Basque is more nominative/accusative in the past tense and ergative/absolutive in the others.

Comment: You may find  [Split ergativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_ergativity) an interesting read, James Grossman.